# How to let a DataGrid dynamically grow on size with its content?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` within a `Grid` and would like the `DataGrid` to resize dynamically when a user writes text in a row of the `DataGrid`.

Example:

```
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
```

If a user writes `Hello World` in Cell 1, then we have:

```
| Hello W| Cell 2 |
```

Is it possible to let the `DataGrid` dynamically resize to:

```
| Hello World | Cell 2|
```

Comment: @GayotFow Yes, I use XAML to design my GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ColumnWidth`

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" />
```

or

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="Auto" />
```